# Internationalization in angular 8 to translate whole application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internationalization, translate

I want to translate my whole application with selected language. I got a example which is using i18n to translate. but i am not understand that how to implement it in my application.

Comment: I don't think this is the right place to find help with your problem, because StackOverflow is specifically for getting answers to coding problems. If you have written some code which you are having problems with, then you could post the code and explain the specific problem you are having. Otherwise, you might do better to do an online search for more information about internationalisation in angular 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just follow my few instructions for better understanding.

1. install ngx-translate npm package in your application.

```
npm i @ngx-translate/core --save
```

2. now you need to install http-loader

```
npm install @ngx-translate/http-loader --save
```

3. Now paste this code into your AppModule.ts file

```
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: myHttpLoader, 
          deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export function myHttpLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

4. Create translation files for languages (like hindi, english etc.) in your /assets/i18n/ folder.

```
  //1. first file name: en.json
  { 
    "Title":"Welcome"
  }

  //2. second file name: hi.json
  {
    "Title":"स्वागत हे"
  }

//Note: you can use google translate to convert into any language.
```

5. Import translate service in your component ts file.

```
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.addLangs(['en', 'hi'])
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    translate.use('en');
  }

  //if user on change language
  switchLanguage(language: string) {
    this.translate.use(language);
  }
}
```

6. in html file

```
  <p translate>Title</p>

  <button (click)="switchLanguage('en')">English</button>

  <button (click)="switchLanguage('hi')">Hindi</button>
```

keep coding. enjoy!

I hope it is helpful for you. :)

Comment: Thanks for explained in easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular version 8, I recommend you to use the [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) package. It comes with much more features than Angular's version 8 an is pretty simple to implement. As far as I remember it was developed by one of the team member to compensate the limitations of the i18.

`npm install @ngx-translate/core --save`

It's pretty easy to install: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/master/README.md#installation

It relies on `.json` files as key values pair to store/access the translated values.

If you plan to upgrade to the version 9 and above you should take a look at the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/i18n) since now it has improved quite a lot.