# ngx-translate - Angular Version 11

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

```
export function TranslationLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): any {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/assets/i18n/');
  }
```

Works fine on local env, however receiving not found error for en.json during runtime in builds.

Comment: You can check the given link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542657/internationalization-in-angular-8-to-translate-whole-application/61543106#61543106

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `'/assets/i18n/'` to `'./assets/i18n/'`.

I believe your build might not be putting your assets directly under `/assets`. One thing you can do is build locally and check if everything is built according to your expectation.

Comment: @nithinv96 Would you mind accepting my answer? Thank you.